# Will water spill out of filled capillary tube, if raised from water?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, water, fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

if to raise a filled capillary tube from the level of water,  will the inside will spill out? or will it keep stuck inside?

imagine a capillary tube put in water, the water rises inside the capillary tube
then I pull up the tube, to see what will happen
will the water fall-off, or will be picked up with the capillary tube?

maybe you can also give the break-even formula between stuck inside and fall off?

Comment: [Related?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89223/)

Answer (score 2):

It will remain stuck inside.
Reason:
Water rises in a capillary tube because of surface tension.It rises till the force on the water column due to surface tension balances the weight of the water.
So when you take a capillary tube out of water no net force acts on the water column because its weight has been balanced by the surface tension.
Hence it remains at rest by virtue of inertia.

Answer (score 0):

The tube would empty. Once removed there would be surface tension pulling the water up on the top of the tube, but now there would also be surface tension on the bottom of the tube pulling down. The downward force would of course be in addition to gravity and the water would pour out of the tube.